# Is there a way to take out expression for reusing in various mixins (like function)?

Tags: less

I have two mixins which use same expression for calculate a value @c, but the value applies to different properties.

```
.mixin1(@a, @b){
   @c: /* some complex expression with @a and @b */;
   width: @c;
}

.mixin2(@a, @b){
   @c: /* same expression like in mixin1 */;
   height: @c;
}
```

How to take out expression for reusing in various mixins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make mixins to emulate functions:

```
.mixin1(@a, @b) {
    .my-complex-expression(@a, @b);
    width: @result;
}

.mixin2(@a, @b) {
    .my-complex-expression(@a, @b);
    height: @result;
}

.my-complex-expression(@a, @b) {
    @result: ((@a + @b) / 2);
}
```

(Note that it could be the only `@result` variable per scope, so in a real project code one would use some long "unique" names for a "return variables". E.g. `@<function-name>-result` or so...)